# SETERROR SWIFT - Parecido a Android

Tags: swift, xcode

En primero lugar mi objetivo es poder replicar el seterror de Android en Swift,

Para ello estoy intentando seguir la siguiente pregunta de Stack

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30574484/displaying-validation-error-on-ios-uitextfield-similar-to-androids-textview-set

En unas de sus respuestas encontre la siguiente solucion

```
    private var rightViews = NSMapTable<UITextField, UIView>(keyOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.weakMemory, valueOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.strongMemory)
private var errorViews = NSMapTable<UITextField, UIView>(keyOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.weakMemory, valueOptions: NSPointerFunctions.Options.strongMemory)

extension UITextField {
    // Add/remove error message
    func setError(_ string: String? = nil, show: Bool = true) {
        if let rightView = rightView, rightView.tag != 999 {
            rightViews.setObject(rightView, forKey: self)
        }



        // Remove message
        guard string != nil else {
            if let rightView = rightViews.object(forKey: self) {
                self.rightView = rightView
                rightViews.removeObject(forKey: self)
            } else {
                self.rightView = nil
            }

            if let errorView = errorViews.object(forKey: self) {
                errorView.isHidden = true
                errorViews.removeObject(forKey: self)
            }

            return
        }

        // Create container
        let container = UIView()
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Create triangle
        let triagle = TriangleTop()
        triagle.backgroundColor = .clear
        triagle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.addSubview(triagle)

        // Create red line
        let line = UIView()
        line.backgroundColor = .red
        line.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.addSubview(line)

        // Create message
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = string
        label.textColor = .white
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250), for: .horizontal)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.addSubview(label)

        // Set constraints for triangle
        triagle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true
        triagle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
        triagle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        triagle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true

        // Set constraints for line
        line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3).isActive = true
        line.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: triagle.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        line.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        line.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        // Set constraints for label
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: line.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        if !show {
            container.isHidden = true
        }
        // superview!.superview!.addSubview(container)
//        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(container)
        self.addSubview(container)

        // Set constraints for container
        container.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: superview!.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        container.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview!.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        // Hide other error messages
        let enumerator = errorViews.objectEnumerator()
        while let view = enumerator!.nextObject() as! UIView? {
            view.isHidden = true
        }

        // Add right button to textField
        let errorButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        errorButton.tag = 999
        errorButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_error"), for: .normal)
        errorButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.height, height: frame.size.height)
        errorButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(errorAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        rightView = errorButton
        rightViewMode = .always

        // Save view with error message
        errorViews.setObject(container, forKey: self)
    }

    // Show error message
    @IBAction
    func errorAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let errorButton = sender as! UIButton
        let textField = errorButton.superview as! UITextField

        let errorView = errorViews.object(forKey: textField)
        if let errorView = errorView {
            errorView.isHidden.toggle()
        }

        let enumerator = errorViews.objectEnumerator()
        while let view = enumerator!.nextObject() as! UIView? {
            if view != errorView {
                view.isHidden = true
            }
        }

        // Don't hide keyboard after click by icon
//                UIViewController.isCatchTappedAround = false
    }
}

class TriangleTop: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }

        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.maxX / 2.0), y: rect.minY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.minX / 2.0), y: rect.maxY))
        context.closePath()

        context.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }
}
```

El cual es una extension de UITextField el cual arma a codigo un contenedor el cual le mete un triangulo y arma el resto del texto y fondo pero cuando lo va a agregar a la vista veo que realiza

```
       UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.addSubview(container)
```

Lo cual provoca que lo que muestra mi error se vaya al final de la pantalla quedando inutil

Como se ve en la siguiente imagen [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si agrega el icono en el medio de la caja pero el "conteiner" que contiene el fondo negro con la string de error se va directo al fondo,

Mi pregunta es como yo podria acomodar este codigo para que no se vaya al final sino siempre abajo de mi caja ??

lo que intento replicar es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

si tu objetivo es motrar una vista con una imagen tipo un triangulo rojo en el textfield para mostrar un alerta al usuario de error puedes probar el siguiente codigo.

```
 @IBAction func searchProduct(_ sender: UIButton){
    if searchTextField.text != ""{
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        dat.loadData(params: parameters.Endpoint(endpoint: end), completion:{ (resultados: resultados<productResponse>) in
        //parse response
        })
    }else{
        //ocurrio un error la contraseña esta vacia por ejemplo un campo en blanco.
        let image = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "F071"))
        image.tintColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.7921568627, green: 0.09019607843, blue: 0.09019607843, alpha: 1)
        searchTextField.rightView = image
        searchTextField.rightViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

el else muestra un triangulo rojo parecido al que muestras en la imagen. si lo que quieres es mostrarlo despues de procesar la respuesta pues lo haces en la parte anterior del else en caso de que la respuesta del request sea contraseña invalida, algún control que tenga tu api para ello. Si deseas quitarle el triangulo cunado el user empiece a escribir entonces debes implementar uno de los delegados del TextField.

Comment: edite mi pregunta para mas claridad pero no es lo que necesito con exactitud, aparte del triangulo necesito mostrar un texto de error como lo hace en android